# In Rails, how drop into debugger when a condition is met

Tags: ruby-on-rails, debugging

Let's say that `foo` is created, changed and saved many times when a program runs.

Usually, `foo.bar == "sensible value"`, but occassionally, `foo.bar == "crazy value"`.

Is there some way I can run `rails server --debugger`, and have it only drop into the debugging console at the point where `foo.bar == "crazy value"`?

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried

```
if foo.bar == "crazy value"
  require 'ruby-debug'; debugger
end
```

This should place a breakpoint that triggers when you run `bundle exec rails server` normally, and only when `foo.bar` has the value you (don't) want.

If you are using bundler, and Ruby 1.9 make sure you have

```
gem 'ruby-debug19', :require => 'ruby-debug'
```

in your Gemfile (in the development and test group).

Comment: Hi, thanks. Yes, I thought of a conditional breakpoint, and if I had a strong hunch where foo.bar was being set to "crazy value", then I would use it. However, I don't, so I'm hoping to drop into the debugger from any point in the entire app that sets foo.bar to "crazy value". Is that possible?

Comment: Define setter for foo.bar and put code provided in answer there.